# Creating a "loading..." view using iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How to create that black/gray modal popup kind of view that many apps use, when some long pending operation is in progress?

Like when using location based services, loading a webpage, the screen goes dim and there is a modal view showing a spinning icon "Please wait..."

Example in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to avoid undocumented api you can also take a look at [MBProgressHUD](http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD). It's similar to UIProgressHUD and even has some additional features.

Answer (score 17):

This is actually the undocumented (in 2.2.1 anyway) UIProgressHUD. Create one like this:

In your .h:

```
@interface UIProgressHUD : NSObject 
- (UIProgressHUD *) initWithWindow: (UIView*)aWindow; 
- (void) show: (BOOL)aShow; 
- (void) setText: (NSString*)aText; 
@end
```

In your .m:

```
- (void) killHUD: (id)aHUD 
{ 
[aHUD show:NO]; 
[aHUD release]; 
} 

- (void) presentSheet 
{ 
id HUD = [[UIProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[contentView superview]]; 
[HUD setText:@"Doing something slow. Please wait."]; 
[HUD show:YES]; 
[self performSelector:@selector(killHUD:) withObject:HUD afterDelay:5.0]; 
}
```

Comment: Can this be used and submitted to the App Store?

Comment: Yes, this is not linking to private API. We’ve done something similar with buttons on the UIAlertView, went through review with no problems.

Comment: Note that the situation has changes since my last comment, nowadays you probably won’t get into the App Store with this.

Comment: @zoul Why has the situation changed? Is this now a private API or something?

Comment: There are two ways of using private API. The first one is linking to private frameworks, the second one is using undocumented calls from the public frameworks. The latter (which we are doing here) used to go through reviews fine, but since some months ago Apple now rejects it, too. In other words, this was always a private API, not described in the official docs and therefore not guaranteed to work, stay or get you through the review.

Answer (score 11):

I think the simplest (a few lines of code), fully documented and most beautiful way is to use the UIAlertView with a UIActivityIndicatorView:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/uialertview-without-buttons-please-wait-dialog.html

[image: UIAlertView with UIActivityIndicatorView]
<sub>(source: [iosdevelopertips.com](http://iosdevelopertips.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/alert3-204x300.png))</sub>

Comment: This was a great solution... but no longer appears to work with iOS 7.

Answer (score 4):

If you add a UIView as a subview of the main window it will cover the entire UI. Make it partially transparent and partially translucent and it will look like a popup.

This example shows how to [fade the Default.png splash screen](http://michael.burford.net/2008/11/fading-defaultpng-when-iphone-app.html), starting with that it's pretty straightforward to add a couple methods to your application delegate (that has a pointer to the main window) to present and dismiss the progress view.

Comment: Hi duncanwilcox, I wanted this also... fading default.png screen... :) Thanks... You seems to answer questions which I still have not asked... :D

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Wordpress iPhone app (http://iphone.wordpress.org/) for an example of how to do this without using any undocumented API's.

Answer (score 1):

I use **LoadingHUDView** for this purpose, and it works always.

get [LoadingHUDView.m](http://yonseiwonjuapp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/YonseiWonjuApp/Classes/LoadingHUDView.m) and [LoadingHUDView.h](http://yonseiwonjuapp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/YonseiWonjuApp/Classes/LoadingHUDView.h) and do the following in your base class (or whatever)

```
#pragma mark ActivityIndicator Methods

-(void) showModalActivityIndicator:(NSString *)message 
{
        loadingView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]retain];//  origional
        //loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; //testing
        loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; //[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.3];
        LoadingHUDView *loadHud = [[LoadingHUDView alloc] initWithTitle:message];
        loadHud.center = CGPointMake(160, 290);
        [loadingView addSubview:loadHud];
        [loadHud startAnimating];
        [loadHud release];
        [loadingView setAlpha:0.0];
          [self.tableView addSubview:loadingView];
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeOutSync" context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [loadingView setAlpha:0.5];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) hideModalActivityIndicator {
    if (loadingView) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeOutSync" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector (removeTranparentView) ];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [loadingView setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
}

-(void)removeTranparentView
{
    [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
    [loadingView release];
    loadingView = nil;
}
```

HOPE THIS HELPS.
thank you

Comment: You may use it as :     
    [self showModalActivityIndicator:@"Logging you in..."];

Answer (score 0):

In XIB file, place UIView and UIActivityIndicatorView.
Set ActivityIndicatorView Property SetAnimated to Yes.

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView*              m_LoadingView;

While Starting long operations, Add the LoadingView to the view

```
m_LoadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
m_LoadingView.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:m_LoadingView];
```

After completing the process, Remove LoadingView from super view.
    [m_LoadingView removeFromSuperView];