# How do I show a loading bezel on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, loading

I'm building an application where it loads contents off of the web to populate a TableView.

I would like to add some sort of loading indicator so that the screen won't just contain the blank table.

I was thinking about something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [iclarified.com](http://www.iclarified.com/images/tutorials/698/3363/3363.png))</sub>

I've been trying to look it up on documentation and Google, but to be honest don't know what to search for. Any pointers? Or is there any other way I should do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a "loading..." view using iPhone SDK...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823080/creating-a-loading-view-using-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two possible ways to do it:

1. The lazy way: Create a transparent PNG image containing the bezel and the loading... text. Display it on the screen and put a `UIProgressView` on top of it.
2. The better way: Use http://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the UIActivityIndicatorView

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html